# How to repair Java in Ubuntu after trying to switch to Java 6 using update-java-alternatives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, apt

I tried to switch from Java 5 to Java 6 using the "update-java-alternatives" command like explained on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

But afterwards I get the following error when I tried to execute java:

```
root@webserver:~# java
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I also tried to reinstall the java binaries using "apt-get" but I didn't succeed reinstalling it. I would like to post the "apt-get" errors, but unfortunately I don't know how to print out the error messages in English and not in German.

My system is a Ubuntu 8.04 ROOT server.

Here is the (Google translated) english text tring to install Java 6 again:

```
root@server:~# apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
Reading package lists ... Ready
Dependency tree
Reading state information ... Ready
sun-java6-jdk is already the newest version.
sun-java6-jdk set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 86 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Set up a sun-java6-bin (6-03-0ubuntu2) ...
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
dpkg: error processing sun-java6-bin (- configure):
 Subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sun-java6-bin
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I hope that this might help you helping me.

Comment: What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: I just get this: java version "1.6.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.6.0_03-b05, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is saying that it doesn't have enough memory. Have you tried to run it with memory limiting parameters, like `java -Xms64m -Xmx512m` (adjust the values to your server available memory)?

Comment: Yes still the same error. I don't think that it is really a issue of memory as there is plenty of memory free.

Comment: I would flip this around: increase these values and try again - like: **java -Xms128m -Xmx768m**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying the install again, this way:

`apt-get --reinstall install sun-java6-jdk`

This will reinstall the software completely, rather than trying to configure what is already there.

Comment: I tried you command, but I get almost the same error. It seems that the "sun-java6-bin" is causing the error.

Comment: I would try the above command with the sun-java6-bin package as well. You might want to remove the packages and try again. I agree, too, with the other poster that Java is saying there isn't enough memory: perhaps Java itself is not reserving enough for its needs...